# MySQL connection using TLS without certs

Tags: mysql, ssl

I noticed something strange when configuring required TLS connections to MySQL, when I connect to MySQL and examine the session variables it states that I am using a cipher as shown below. As I understand it you need to provide a client cert to authenticate/validate with the server.

In this particular server I have not set up SSL so most config is as is from install, can anyone explain to me how this works?

[image: MySQL Workbench]

Comment: Most likely your OS package for MySQL installs  a self-signed certificate for your server, and you clicked "Accept" when the client warned you when connecting to an unknown host.

Comment: I suspected as such, I attempted to ,look through my certificates on the local machine but could not identify any, are there any links to describe how this works I would like to know more, especially how a server can automatically provide a client cert to be used.

Comment: You need a server certificate, not a client certificate. You could set it up to require a client certificate, but it's highly unlikely that you did this. You would be 100% sure if you had.